# angular strap typeahead filter otions issue

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-strap

I am trying to use typeahead from angular strap.

I have array for typeahead:

```
`$scope.icons = [
    {value: 'idGear', label: 'Gear'},
    {value: 'idGlobe', label: 'Globe'},
    {value: 'oidHeart', label: 'Heart'},
    {value: 'camera', label: 'Camera'}
  ];`
```

and want to filter array on `label` so I added:

`bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons|filter:{label:$viewValue}"`

but when I select first item in input I see `value`(idGear) but not `label` (Gear)
It works fine for last item `{value: 'camera', label: 'Camera'}` if `value` is allmoust the same as `label`

here is planker with issue demonstartion  http://plnkr.co/edit/blXEtsCG9RRBctkniHAW?p=preview

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass it the full object and from there you can manipulate it accordingly:

```
<input type="text" 
class="form-control"
ng-model="selectedIcon" 
data-min-length="0" 
data-html="1"
bs-options="icon as icon.label for icon in icons|filter:{label:$viewValue}" 
placeholder="Enter icon" bs-typeahead>
```

i.e. if you want to use the value

```
var myval = selectedIcon.value;
var mylab = selectedIcon.Label;
```